# Performing actions in order (not asynchronously) on different nodes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Here is an illustration of what I am trying to do:

[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    let mySquare1 = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize:CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    let mySquare2 = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize:CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        mySquare1.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y:100)
        mySquare2.position = CGPoint(x: 300, y:100)

        mySquare1.fillColor = SKColor.blueColor()
        mySquare2.fillColor = SKColor.blueColor()

        self.addChild(mySquare1)
        self.addChild(mySquare2)

        let moveAction1 = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x:250, y:100), duration: 1)
        mySquare1.runAction(moveAction1)

        let moveAction2 = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x:300, y:350), duration: 1)
        mySquare2.runAction(moveAction2)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    }
}
```

My problem is, I am trying to move the rectangles synchronously (not asynchronously). That is, I want my first rectangle start moving, finish its movement, stop. And then, start my second rectangle moving, finish its movement and stop.

Currently what happens is that, when I run my program, they both start moving at the same time.

I also found `SKAction.sequence` for actions to play in order, however, I only can use this for actions on the same object. Not in different objects like in my example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to move the two rectangles sequentially (not in parallel), you could use the `completion` property of the first action like this ([apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483103-runaction)):

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene {
    let mySquare1 = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize:CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    let mySquare2 = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize:CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        mySquare1.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y:100)
        mySquare2.position = CGPoint(x: 300, y:100)
        mySquare1.fillColor = SKColor.blueColor()
        mySquare2.fillColor = SKColor.blueColor()
        self.addChild(mySquare1)
        self.addChild(mySquare2)
        let move1 = SKAction.moveToX(250, duration: 1.0)
        let move2 = SKAction.moveToY(250, duration: 1.0)
        self.mySquare1.runAction(move1,completion: {
            self.mySquare2.runAction(move2)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This works as expected! I was hoping to find a simpler way, but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the SKAction for running blocks. Then sequence them from the scene.

For example:

```
func example() {
    let firstRectMove = SKAction.runBlock({
        let move1 = SKAction.moveToX(20, duration: 1.0)
        let move2 = SKAction.moveToY(20, duration: 1.0)
        rec1.runAction(SKAction.sequence([move1,move2]))
    })
    let actionWait = SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0)
    let secondRectMove = SKAction.runBlock({

        let move1 = SKAction.moveToX(20, duration: 1.0)
        let move2 = SKAction.moveToY(20, duration: 1.0)
        rec2.runAction(SKAction.sequence([move1,move2]))
    })
    //self is an SKScene or any other node really...
    self.runAction(SKAction.sequence([firstRectMove,actionWait,secondRectMove]))
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. However, it does not work as expected. :( Please see my edit in the original question.

Comment: I also tested the same code in iPhone and same result. (I thought maybe the simulator is wrong.)

Comment: I just realized if I add a `waitForDuration(1)` in the middle of those two actions, it works as expected. However, it's ugly.

Comment: @Salt totally forgot to add the wait. I edited it into my answer.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/sequence:) we don't need `waitForDuration()` . It says: "The duration of the sequence action is the sum of the durations of the actions in the sequence." I don't know why it does not work as expected without `waitForDuration()`.

Comment: @Sait It is because it is waiting for the duration of the block to run. The entire block completes as soon as it starts the initial sequence. The block does not have a duration. Does that make sense?

Comment: We explicitly set the `duration: 1.0` on the `SKAction.moveTo()` function. If blocks don't have duration, then the explanation in the documentation given above is irrelevant, which still does not make sense to me.

Comment: You could try using https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/customActionWithDuration:actionBlock: I think this is what you are looking for. Runs a block with a duration.

Answer (score 3):

As Alessandro Ornano suggests, a way to accomplish this is run your first action with a completion block, where a block of code runs after the completion of the original action. A downside to this approach is that it can create a [pyramid of doom](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/12/08/swift-optional-pyramids-of-doom.html) when you need to chain together more than two actions at a time.

An alternative way to avoid to the "pyramid" is to define a method that calls itself recursively for each subsequent action in an array:

```
func runInSequence(actions:[(node:SKNode,action:SKAction)], index:Int) {
    if index < actions.count {
        let node = actions[index].node
        let action = actions[index].action
        node.runAction(action) {
            // Avoid retain cycle
            [weak self] in
            self?.runInSequence(actions, index: index+1)
        }
    }
}
```

To use this, define/create an array that stores the nodes and actions you want to run in sequence, and call the method with the starting index:

```
    let nodesAndActions:[(node:SKNode,action:SKAction)] = [
        (mySquare1,moveAction1),
        (mySquare2,moveAction2)
    ]
    runInSequence(nodesAndActions, index: 0)
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer. Simple and beautiful. Thank you.

Comment: Agreed, @Sait, this is masterful, elegant and inspiring. I have one question... is it possible to interrupt this, midstream? That would make it amazing.